Real singular locus of real curve
Let $f \in \mathbb{R}[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ be an homogeneous polynomial defining the projective real curve $C = V(f)$. I assume that $C$ is integral over $\mathbb{R}$.
I am wondering: What can we say about the real-valued points of the singular locus of $C$? Provided that $C$ is singular, will there always be real-valued singular points? If in general the answer is no, what if we assume that $\deg(f)$ is even?

Example: If $\deg(f) = 2$, then the answer is yes, because $f$ is a product of two lines, which are mutually complex conjugate (since $f$ is defined over $\mathbb{R}$). This gives rise to a single real singular point.

Excluded case: If $\text{def}(f) = 3$, and dropping the assumption that $C$ is integral, then I could take $f = (x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2)\cdot l$ where $l$ is any real line. This obviously defines two singular points (the intersection points of the irreducible components), but neither is real-valued. An analogous argument works for $\deg(f) = 4$.

Best,
Clemens

No, there need not be a real-valued singular point, even if $\deg f$ is even. The curve cut out by $$(y^2+z^2)(y^2+(x+z)^2)+(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$$ is a counterexample: this has a singularity at $[0:\pm i: 1]$, but no other singularities.
The idea for finding this curve is that we take a product of two pairs of complex lines which are conjugate and both pass through $[0:\pm i:1]$, and add some multiple of the square of a smooth curve which passes through that point as well. Generically, the result should be what we're looking for, so all one has to do is to pick the multiple in a non-unlucky way. Verification that these are the only two singular points is a bit messy and is best done on a large blackboard or via a computer algebra system.

That is a very nice example! Thank you very much.
